# Add Cluster Items onClick over Expandable List View

Tags: android-activity, maps, cluster-computing, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

First of all I'm sorry for my bad English :X

Iam quite a newbie in Android App development and Iam about to develope an app which gives the user informations like free park-places in town.
The app is based on Google Maps.

My Problem:
My app starts and shows a Google Maps Layout. Over an ExpandableListView the User can open a overview about the Parking-Locations. 
If the user click on a Child Item in the ExpListView a new Cluster item should be generated at the MapsLayout.

How can I give the OnClick data to the MainActivity? I want that the MainActivity 'knew' which Item is clicked by the User! 
Im glad about every answer :)

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

// constructor
public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern)
{
    this.parentItems = parents;
    this.childtems = childern;
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity)
{
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.activity = activity;
}

// method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
//  Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


    child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

    TextView textView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
    }

    // get the textView reference and set the value
    textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
    textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

    // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Tried to insert connection to MapsActivity but doesnt work!
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

// method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
// Implement this method as per your requirement
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
    }

    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount()
{
    return parentItems.size();
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition)
{
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
{
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return false;
}
 }
```

MapsActivity (Main)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClustermanager ;
private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpClusterer();


    // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
    ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
    expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
    expandableList.setClickable(true);

    // Set the Items of Parent
    setGroupParents();
    // Set The Child Data
    setChildData();


    // Create the Adapter
    MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);


    adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);

    // Set the Adapter to expandableList
    expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
   // expandableList.setOnChildClickListener();


}
// method to add parent Items
public void setGroupParents()
{
    parentItems.add("Parkhäuser");
}
public void setChildData()
{

    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();

    child = new ArrayList<String>();
    child.add("Park1");
    child.add("Park2");
    child.add("Park3");
    child.add("Park4");

    childItems.add(child);

}
private void setUpClusterer()
{
    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(47.99481, 7.84856), 10 )) ;

    //Initialisierung des Managers mit dem Context (this) und der Map
    //Activity erbt von Context deswegen können wir dem Konstruktor 'this' mitgeben

    mClustermanager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap() );

    //Zeigt der Map die Listener des ClusterManagers
    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener((mClustermanager));
    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClustermanager);
    //Hinzufügen der Markierungen zum Cluster Manager
    addItems() ;
}

private void addItems(){
    //Startkoordinaten des ersten Markers --> Bahnhofsgarage
    double lat = 47.99673 ;
    double lng = 7.84152 ;

    //Hinzufügen von 10 weiteren Punkten

    for(int i = 1; i <14; i++){
        if(i==1)
        {   //Konzerthaus
            lat = 47.99602 ;
            lng = 7.84220;
        }
        if(i==2){
            //Volksbank
            lat = 47.99783 ;
            lng = 7.84322;
        }
        if(i==3){
            //am Bahnhof
            lat = 47.99892 ;
            lng = 7.84310;
        }
        if(i==4){
            //Uni-FMF/Vf
            lat = 48.00135 ;
            lng = 7.84481;
        }
        if(i==5){
            //unterlinden
            lat = 47.99811 ;
            lng = 7.84876;
        }
        if(i==6){
            //schwarzwaldcity
            lat = 47.99760 ;
            lng = 7.85090;
        }
        if(i==7){
            //Rotteckring
            lat = 47.99618 ;
            lng = 7.84732;
        }
        if(i==8){
            //Am Zähringer Tor
            lat = 47.99921 ;
            lng = 7.85350;
        }if(i==9){
            //Karlsbau
            lat = 47.99757 ;
            lng = 7.85366;
        }if(i==10){
            //Landratsamt
            lat = 47.99969 ;
            lng = 7.85758;
        }if(i==11){
            //Schlossberg
            lat = 47.99654 ;
            lng = 7.85758;
        }if(i==12){
            //Schwabentor
            lat = 47.99054 ;
            lng = 7.85833;
        }if(i==13){
            //Am Martinstor
            lat = 47.99281 ;
            lng = 7.84715;
        }if(i==14){
            //Uni Kolleg Gebäude
            lat = 47.98797 ;
            lng = 7.87129;
        }

        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat,lng) ;
        mClustermanager.addItem(offsetItem);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! After research I make ExpandableAdpater an inner class of MapsActivity! Now i can put data between both classes and use Methods also!